# Convert complex xpath to css

Tags: css, xpath

I wonder is this possible to convert complex XPATH into CSS path? by 'complex' I mean 'where' selector (in the example below it is `[td[2]/span/text()='"+myNumber+"']`)
So, this is my expression from Chrome console:

```
$x("//*[@id='tab52174-0']/table/tbody/tr[6][td[2]/span/text()='"+myNumber+"']/td[6]/span")
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: It is not possible. CSS does not have decendant depending selectors